# sending an email to the user depending on statusmy

Tags: php, mysql

i created a table in the database (mysql),and i write a code for inserting data in the datbase using php.values are inserted properly.here i set the status column value as deactive.when user created in that time ,we send a mail to the user to active the link ,means my site and then status column has to changed as active.

```
my db table contains the following columns

name,email,pwd,status,lastlogin,security qun,ans
```

when user is created in that time i set the status as deactive.in that time i want to sent a mail(in this mail,i want to send the link to their account) to the user to active their account ,then only user goes to the next process.after that when user open the mail & click that link,the status column has to changed as active in the database.how can i do this,anyone help me..

Comment: Have you tried anything, or do you expect a complete solution to your problem?

Comment: actually i dont know ,how can i do this one,just i set the status column as deactive

Comment: i know php and mysql lightly .actually just now only i use the php-mysql connectivity ,thats why i dont know ,how to do this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to solve the problem is:

1. make the field 'status' as varchar not int.
2. when you are inserting user information for the first time, make a random string and insert it in the status field.
3. say your random string you have created is 'lka342lkjasd8234kl2324ljklj2'. send the link with the string as a parameter.
4. when the link is clicked in the script check the verification string matches the value in your status table.
5. if it matches then show message that his account is verified and change the value of the field to 1 (as 1 indicates a active account)
6. if the string doesn't matches then show message the verification link is wrong.

in another way you can make another table for storing verification string. and make the status fiend an integer. set 0 initially and make it 1 when verified, and check the verification with the new table.

Comment: i set a random string to the status column.here i dont know how can i send a mail to the user

Comment: use mail() function, check php documentation of mail() function from php.net .

Answer (score 0):

You can create column called **activation_code**, send an email to user with link, which will contain this **activation_code**. Link like this [www.example.com/active.php?activation_code=AABBCCDDEEFF](http://www.example.com/active.php?activation_code=AABBCCDDEEFF), when user click this link you can get **activation_code**, find a user at database and change **status**. Also you can create column **activation_expires** which will contain a date when activation code will expire.